# unload template file with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a hundreds of views, in which each of view loads some templates files. There is one of the templates needs to remove from the view. I can remove it manually one by one from the views by commenting it out.

But is there any simple ways to unload the template. The template is in .php extension (chat.php). I may put this script to unload the this php file in the footer template. The footer is inside the body tag.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this a PHP question? Code please.

Comment: No, it is javascript question. I need javascript code to unload a file of php.

Comment: What do you mean by "unload"?

Comment: Because first I load the template with php. $this->load->view(chat.php). Now I want to unload it with javascript. What I mean by "unload" is NOT  to load it anymore.

Comment: You want Javascript executing on a page to retroactively remove a template used to generate that page?  Or do you mean that you want the template not to be used on future accesses to the site?

Comment: I want the template not to be used NOW. lol

Comment: Sounds like you need `$('#chat').remove();` or something to that effect, but without code it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->view(chat.php)
```

is  a server-side statement. So a real unload is not possible.

I see 2 possibilities to come closer to your question.
1. You can search for the container of the chat.php and delete it. Now your chat.php isnt there anymore but initial it was loaded.
2. Hide the chat.php if its only for layout porpose.

THe problem for both cases is, that there is always network traffic for the chat php. if you want to "unload" the chat php you have to do ist with php. Otherwise you can implement a frontend mvc-framework like Angularjs. Then you are able to not load some templates on javascript conditions.